# Creating multiple files in R with a content inside

Tags: r

I'm learning R right now but I can't find a solution for my problem. I'd like to create 100 files with a text line inside, let's say "Hello world!". Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop and `write_lines` for example:

```
for(i in 1:100) { 
  write_lines("Hello World", path = sprintf("file%s.txt", i))#
}
```

or use `mapply`

```
mapply(write_lines, path = sprintf("file%s.txt", 1:100), x = "Hello World")
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That what I was trying to do but I wasn't familiar with the "sprintf".